# Como diminuir o processamento em lua? ou muti hash?

Tags: lua, lua-table, detecção-de-colisão, love2d

Eu tenho um table com várias tables de 5 posições onde as duas primeiras são a posição num plano cartesiano.

```
    --Table with water collors
colors = {{r=15,g=94,b=156},{r=35,g=137,b=218},{r=28,g=163,b=236},{r=90,g=188,b=216},{r=116,g=204,b=244}}
points = {}
for i=1,10000 do
    j = love.math.random(1,table.getn(colors)-1)
    table.insert(points,{i,i,colors[j].r,colors[j].g,colors[j].b})
```

Estou fazendo um método para alterar a posição(as duas primeiras posições do vetor) desse objeto, mas pra isso preciso saber se tem algum objeto em cima do outro, ou seja se os dois primeiros valores da table coincidem com o valor de outra table, estou assumindo que comparar um por um é inviável,pensei em usar o x e y como key para um hash, mas não sei se isso é possível, alguém sabem alguma alternativa?

Comment: LÖVE contém funções para detecção de colisão: https://love2d.org/wiki/love.physics

Comment: @lhf normalmente a biblioteca de física do Löve2D não é a melhor opção porque é bem confusa e tem poucos exemplos. Na verdade a maior parte dos objetos dela nem tem exemplo de como usar, precisei estudar implementações do Box2D em outras linguagens para ter uma ideia de como usar.

Answer (score 0):

A detecção de colisão feita por física é muito trabalhosa e a documentação do Löve2D recomenda só usar isso se você tiver certeza que o que quer fazer precisa de física (como um jogo de pinball que fiz uma vez).

Um truque simples que você pode fazer é o seguinte:

1. Divida a sua tela em 4 quadrantes, cada um com uma tabela de objetos que estão naquele quadrante
2. Controle o posicionamento dos objetos mudando eles de tabela quando eles mudarem de quadrante
3. Para um determinado objeto que você sabe qual o quadrante verifique se ele colide com os outros daquele quadrante verificando os quatro quantos do retângulo de borda (bounding box)

Essa forma é bem simples de implementar e deve oferecer o desempenho que você procura. Caso contrário existe ainda uma outra biblioteca em Löve2D chamada bump que permite verificar colisão, ela é mais simples do que a de física e indicada para fazer um personagem caminhar sobre uma plataforma por exemplo, mas é bem mais complicada de usar do que essa estratégia aqui.